# How to override a " Create New" record page with a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have overridden a section of page layout with a vf page.But it is not getting displayed while creating a new record.
How to achieve that?
It is however getting displayed on edit page,but not on create new record page.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In salesforce classic you have to completely override the new page and there is no way to just make a section layout override.